# Should i commit Entity Framework migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

Long story short, im working on a project with multiple people using Entity Framework with PostgreSQL and i ask myself now how we handle migrations.

Assuming from Visual Studio default .gitignore you shouldn't commit these, but how do the other people update there database to the right model without migrations? or for people having an outdated version of the database in there development enviroment?

Comment: Assuming I understood, you'd _have to_ (commit to src ctrl), for the reasons you stated - "people having an outdated version of the database". "Everyone" working on the same app should have the same database (structure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should include your local DB changes, so it can be synchronized with other members of the team. Every member should commit their local migrations changes. What I suggest to you is to have team meetings and have discussions about changes you need to do and prepare tasks that will not cause conflicts with other members.